# Match with all characters after the first 20?

Tags: regex

If I have a string 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf` 20 characters long, I don't want any match.

BUT! I want to match every character after the initial 20.

`asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf` (any additional characters are matched!)

Comment: any specific language or you need it in regex only? you can try with substring after first 20 characters

Comment: Yeah, I'm using JavaScript, but I was wondering if there was a regex way, but yeah, substr() will work fine

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Yeah, I agree with the substr() option, it's easier to read as well. But, it's cool that there is a regex way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a non-capturing group for the first 20 characters and a capturing group thereafter:

```
/(?:^.{20})(.*)/
```

Additionally, you can use slice(20) or substring:

```js
let str = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarafael';
let [,match] = /(?:^.{20})(.*)/.exec(str);
console.log(match)

//easier
console.log(str.slice(20))
```

Comment: The non capture group is useless here.

Answer (score 2):

As you said you are using javascript, I would suggest use `substr(n)` instead of regex solution

```js
var str1 = "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfStackoverflow";
var result = str1.substr(20);  //Stackoverflow
console.log(result)
```

This is quite simple and easy to read